# Laravel : can't insert one column data in classrooms table

Tags: laravel, store, laravel-8

I'm new to the Laravel framework. I want to insert classrooms data i.e.:

- ................
- ................
- quota

This is the classrooms table:

[image: table]

However, when I click "submit", the data from the quota column is not added with the result = **0** while the others are inserted. This is the result of inserting the data:

[image: data]

Also, the return result looks like this:

[image: this]

I've added in $fillable :

[image: fillable]

This is my data insert code:

[image: code]

Comment: look like in mysql default value set to 10 i guess for quota

Comment: can you dd($request->all()); before creating record

Comment: Can you share your validation rules ? As if you do not have a validation for `quota` then `$request->validated()` will not have it also... that seems to be the problem

Comment: Oh right, thank you everyone. I forgot the validation in my project. I already add it and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required'
    'subject_id' => 'required'
    'semester_id' => 'required',
]);

$class = new Classroom();
$class ->name = $request->name;
$class ->subject_id= $request->subject_id;
$class ->semester_id= $request->semester_id;
$class ->description= $request->description;
$class ->quota= $request->quota;
$class ->save();
Toastr::success('Class Room Successfully Save','Success');
return redirect()->route('admin.classrooms.index);
```